# style.css doesn't load on the home page when front-page.php activated (using stock theme)

Tags: css, homepage, frontpage

I promise you I'm not wasting your time with this problem. I have searched through StackExchange for almost 4 hours in the last few days, and even though there are questions with similar titles, I promise you that this problem I'm facing is unique and it was not asked before.

**The problem is this:** When I create a custom `front-page.php` in my theme's directory, Wordpress displays it as my home page as expected, but for some reason, the style.css file does not load in the web browser, thus, I can't modify the content of the front-page.php with CSS. I put a `div` in `front-page.php`, and no matter what I put in style.css, the `div` is unaffected. I have tried this with multiple WordPress installations, and every time it is the same thing. **I'm using one of Wordpress' stock themes, so my functions.php file is not the problem.**

This is either a bug with WordPress, or I am messing up something while I'm configuring the server. This is why I'm going to destroy my server and rebuild it again, and add pictures to show you what I'm doing in every step.

**1-** I'm making a Wordpress installation in a droplet on DigitalOcean, which I set up by one click "OpenLiteSpeed Wordpress" app in their marketplace. So the WordPress set-up is pure.

**2-** I log in to my server via Putty, using SSH keys, as `root`. I create a new user called `daddy`, and add it to the `sudo` group. I install the SSH key for the user `daddy`, and I disallow remote SSH access to the `root` account. I change `PermitRootLogin yes` to `no` and save the file.

**3-** I connect to my server using FileZilla via SFTP method, as the user `daddy`, not as root. And I see that the owner of my WordPress installation files is `www-data`, and the group is also `www-data`.

[image: Step 3]

I check the file permissions, and see that it's set to `644`. So the `www-data` group which owns the WordPress installation has a read permisson, but not a write permission. This is the stock settings that comes with the stock Wordpress installation through DigitalOcean's one-click apps.

**4-** Now, as the user `daddy`, I try to create a front-page.php file, and as expected FileZilla gives me this error:

[image: Step 4]

**5-** I go to the terminal and use `id daddy` to see which groups the user `daddy` belongs to.

[image: Step 5]

As expected, it belongs to the group `daddy` and group `sudo`, because when I create a new user in the terminal, it creates a group with the same name and it makes that group the primary group of the user. This happens by default, right?

So at this point, I know that I should add the user `daddy` to the `www-data` group, so both the FTP user that's trying to modify the server (which is `daddy` in this case) and the owner of the WordPress installation (which is `www-data`) will belong to the same group (which is `www-data`). I also should give `www-data` group write permissions, so WordPress can modify and update the files in this directory. After doing these, I will be able to create that front-page.php as the user `daddy` in FileZilla.

**6-** In the terminal, I use `gpasswd -a daddy www-data` to add `daddy` to `www-data` group. And then I use `usermod -g www-data daddy`to change the user `daddy`'s primary group to `www-data`. I use `groups daddy` to check and see this:

[image: Step6]

As shown by the terminal, the user `daddy`'s primary group is now `www-data`, and it also belongs to the `sudo` group. (As expected, `usermod g` deleted the user from its previous primary group called `daddy`.)

**7-** In the terminal, I use `sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/html` and `sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/html` to set the correct read/write permissions for the `www-data` group. This is so that WordPress would have write permissions for all these files. I check the file permissions in FileZilla, and the files in the theme folder is now set to `664`, meaning that WordPress has now write permission too.

[image]

**8-** In FileZilla, I try to create a front-page.php, and it works. I set its permissions to `664` as well, giving WordPress a write permission for this file, so that I can modify its content using WordPress' Theme Editor.

[image: Step8]

I change my home page settings through WordPress, and when I go to my website, it loads the empty front-page.php. So, everything seems alright.

**9-** On WordPress, I go to Theme Editor, and modify front-page.php. I simply add:

`<div id="hi"> hello world. </div>`.

I go to style.css, and I add:

```
#hi { width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black; }
```

I update the style.css, it saves. I go to my website, which shows front-page.php as its home page, and here is the problem:

[image: Step9]

As you can see, the css code I used to manipulate `<div id="hi">`
 did not render.

**10-** I right-click on Chrome and click "Inspect", and I see that `style.css` hasn't been loaded at all. It's nowhere to be found.

**Here is the thing:** Before I created `front-page.php` and made all the changes in FileZilla and the terminal that were violently depicted in those 9 steps, the main page of the default theme of WordPress loaded just fine. And when I clicked "Inspect" on Chrome, the `style.css` was there, as it should, because the theme was working fine.

So to sum up: In one of these steps, I must be making a mistake that would break WordPress' ability to load "style.css". But what? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your front-page.php file include `wp_head()`? Or `get_header()`?

Comment: Are you working with any cache plugins? The can foul up the best of us when bug hunting.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Hi, thank you for answering. I'm grateful. I checked it and yes it does contain `<?php get_header();?>` as I copied stock `page.php`s content to make the `front-page.php`. And `page.php` is the default template for Single Pages, right?

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt Thank you for answering. I don't have any plugins other than WordPress' stock plugins. The only thing I can see "cache" related is a tab called LiteSpeed Cache that is placed right under the Settings button on the WordPress admin page. It's there because I used "OpenLiteSpeed WordPress Installation". And it's for loading pages faster. I disabled OpenLiteSpeed cache to see if it's being enabled was the problem, but nothing changed. Do you think this might still be the problem though? Something about OpenLiteSpeed installation?

Comment: @DoğukanÖnal it is impossible to say for certain. I have noticed browsers tend to cache CSS files. Open the CSS file directly (view source, find link, click it) then refresh the file to see your changes, after which (if this is the solution) the CSS you added should affect the page.